# Find sum of max values in a single SELECT query

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I have prepared [an SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7e119/2) for my question.

In a word game I run [a custom function](http://postgresql.nabble.com/RETURNS-TABLE-function-ERROR-column-reference-quot-word-quot-is-ambiguous-td5915779.html) to find all words played by a user in her last turn:

[image: app screenshot]

Invalid words have a `score` of `NULL` (could be changed to `-1` if needed).

Valid words have positive `score` and if there are several matching words, then I only need the highest score (and discard the other score).

For example, if a player plays horizontal word "ab" with score 8 and vertical word "ab" with score 2, then she only gets 8 points for that turn.

Here is my test table:

```
CREATE TABLE words(word varchar, score integer);
```

And here I fill it with test data:

```
INSERT INTO words (word, score) VALUES
('ab', 8),  -- word with higher score should be taken
('ab', 2),  -- same word with lower score should be discarded
('xy', 2),
('zz', NULL); -- invalid word marked by NULL (or -1)
```

I can see if an invalid word has been played by

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM words WHERE score IS NULL) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid word played';
END IF;
```

And I can remove duplicate words with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT word, max(score) as score FROM words GROUP BY word;
```

My question is however:

How to combine both statements above to a single `SELECT` statement, so that I:

1. Know if an invalid word has been played
2. The sum of played scores (so that I can update the player's score)

I am looking for a single statement, so that [the custom function](http://postgresql.nabble.com/RETURNS-TABLE-function-ERROR-column-reference-quot-word-quot-is-ambiguous-td5915779.html) is not run several times and preferably without a temporary table.

The result should look like (I am going to call it from another custom PL/pgSQL function):

```
DECLARE
    total_user_score    integer;
    invalid_words_found boolean;

SELECT
    .....,              -- how to calculate this value please?
    .....               -- how to calculate this value please?
INTO STRICT
    total_user_score,
    invalid_words_found
FROM words_check_words(....);  -- avoid calling this function twice

IF invalid_words_found THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION "Invalid words found";
ELSE
    UPDATE games SET user_score = user_score + total_user_score;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(edited to return a boolean for `invalid_words_found`)*
*(edited to use `bool_or` aggregate function)*

If I understood correctly:

```
with cte as (
    select max(score) as score,
           bool_or(score is null) as has_invalid
      from words_check_words(....)
     group by word
)
select coalesce(sum(score), 0) as total_user_score,
       bool_or(has_invalid) as invalid_words_found
  from cte
```

Your custom function would only get called once.

**EDIT:** Integrating into your procedure, it would look something like this:

```
DECLARE
    total_user_score    integer;
    invalid_words_found boolean;

with cte as (
    select max(score) as score,
           bool_or(score is null) as has_invalid
      from words_check_words(....)
     group by word
)
select coalesce(sum(score), 0),
       bool_or(has_invalid)
INTO STRICT
    total_user_score,
    invalid_words_found
FROM cte;

IF invalid_words_found THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION "Invalid words found";
ELSE
    UPDATE games SET user_score = user_score + total_user_score;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
select   coalesce(sum(max_score), 0) as total_user_score,
         count(*) - count(max_score) as invalid_words_found
from     (select   max(score) as max_score
          from     words
          group by word) x
```

See: [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/57906/4)

This assumes that if a word is invalid, it cannot also occur (in another record) with a non-null score.

The `IF` statement would need to look as follows:

```
IF invalid_words_found > 0 THEN
```

... and you could display the number of invalid words in the error message:

```
    RAISE EXCEPTION '% Invalid words found!', invalid_words_found;
```

Comment: Yes. invalid word has always same score of NULL (or -1)

Comment: OK, in this solution it has to be NULL (not -1). If -1 could occur, the SQL would need a little adaptation. Do you need that?

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  word,
  max(
    case 
      when score is null then raise_error('Invalid word: ' || word)::int 
      else score 
    end)
from words
group by word;
```

where the `raise_error` function declared like

```
create function raise_error(text) returns text language plpgsql volatile as
$body$
begin
  raise exception '%', $1;
end $body$;
```

---

To make the query more elegant there is another common-purpose function could be created:

```
create function assert(
  p_cond boolean,
  p_message text,
  p_result anyelement) returns anyelement language plpgsql volatile as
$body$
begin
  if p_cond then
    return p_result;
  else
    raise exception '%', p_message;
  end if;
end $body$;
```

And the query becomes more compact:

```
select 
  word,
  max(assert(score is not null, 'Invalid word: ' || word, score))
from words
group by word;
```